# How to create a Logic App to copy files from one container to another?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have two storage resources with one container each and now I want to make a Logic App to copy files from one container to another one. How to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I copied from one storage account to another :
Create 2 connection strings for each storage account and then
`get content blob` (Source Account) > `Create blob` (Destination account)

Here is the sample screenshot of the flow for your reference
[image]

Comment: Great! This is working fine. Is there any way to keep the copied file same as the original one?

Comment: @Aadhar Do you mean by original one?

Comment: When the above logic app is executed the file from container one named xml1.xml is saved as a file named "copied" in container two. Is there any way to keep the file name as xml1.xml in container the file is copied to?

Comment: @Aadhar Just give the same name near the blob and it will be working fine

Comment: Yes, I did the same, thanks for the help.

Comment: @SwethaKandikonda This was very helpful, I have one similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76003112/how-to-create-a-logic-app-to-copy-files-dynamically-from-on-container-to-another), can you help?