# How to create a logic app to copy files dynamically from on container to another storage blob container?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid

I was checking the [how-to-create-a-logic-app-to-copy-files-from-one-container-to-another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69315931/how-to-create-a-logic-app-to-copy-files-from-one-container-to-another), it looks easy but I want to run this dynamically whenever there is new file uploaded to the source blob storage container, I want to copy that file to another destination blob storage container. How to implement this?

Getting issue with connection in logic app workflows(I am using azure service principal as authentication)

[image]

**Update-1:**

Getting error:
[image]

Comment: Did you tried anything? It would be great if you provide more details like your approach and blockers through images. Then only community members can help

Comment: @vijaya I am not sure how to trigger this logic app whenever there is new file is uploaded to blob. New to azure :|

Comment: i can understand. Refer this MS document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage?tabs=consumption and atleast try something from your end and then let me know wthat you tried and where you need help. Then only we can help

Comment: @vijaya Can you check the updated question with error? It says, `authType` is missing.

Comment: if you follow as i mentioned in my solution you don't get this error as per your previous case. But as per your comments you changed your question. To resolve your error, make a new question by providing your approach and error clearly as this error is not related to this question.

Comment: @vijaya Can you help in this question? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76064304/error-the-authtype-connection-parameter-value-is-not-specified-for-the-on-pre)

Comment: As per your edited image i don't think so your using correct access key. Once check my solution added Access key image.

Comment: @vijaya I am using the exactly the same key as shown in your solution, I was using standard logic app instead of consumption logic app that is the only difference.

Comment: ok. You already make it as a new question so you will get a solution there.

Comment: @vijaya Can you answer it, if you have time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By following this MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage?tabs=consumption) you can go through blob storage connector.
Issue reproduced from my end got expected results by following below steps.

- **First i created Source storage account(vijayastr)** and **destination storage account(vijstr0)** and logic App in azure portal.
- In logic App as per your requirement search for Azure blob storage connector and as shown in below image i have taken connection name as vijconnection , Authentication type as Access key and then provided the details like my source storage account name and key for establishing connection to source blob storage.
  [image]
  [image]
- After connection established as per your requirement taken **When a blob is added or modified trigger** and here in storage account name or blob endpoint it displays **your storage accounts(which you already created)**. Select source blob storage from list and then in container select the container of your source storage account which you already created.(As i said before establishing connection i already created 2 blob storages and blob [containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-portal) for those storage accounts)
  [image]
- Then i have taken **Get blob content action** and selected Source storage account and blob as shown in below image.
  [image]
- After Get blob action for moving blob from source stotage to destination storage taken create blob action.

**Note**: After selecting create blob click on change connection because we are moving data to another blob storage. **Click on change connection and then click on add to create new connection.**

[image]

- After **establishing new connection in create blob action** mention your destination blob storage detail as shown in below image and in blob content take **File Content of previous action Get blob content by using dynamic expression**.
  [image]
- Then save the workflow and Run. Logic App ran successfully as shown in below. Whenever changes done in source storage it trigger the workflow and then it moves blobs uploaded in  source storage to destination storage.
  [image]

Comment: Thanks Vijaya for the detailed answer, sorry that I forgot to mention that the two storage account uses two different subscriptions and two virtual networks but the tenant id is same. In which subscription do I need to create logic app? How is the access key is generated? Is it the one that is available in "Access keys"?

Comment: @Python coder You can create the logic app in either subscription, but you need to ensure that the logic app has access to both storage accounts. Regarding the access key, yes, you can use the access key that is available in the "Access keys" section of the storage account. You can use this key to authenticate your logic app to access the storage account. You can also use Azure AD authentication to authenticate your logic app, which is more secure than using access keys.

Comment: Is there a way to check/verify that logic app has access to both storage accounts? or How to create a logic app which will have access to both storage accounts?

Comment: @Python coder as my mentioned in my solution if you can create connection to blob and you can be able to create blob actions without any errors it means logicapp has access to both storage a/c's . If you are getting errors refer this MS documenthttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage?tabs=consumption#access-storage-accounts-through-virtual-network-integration and try to access them behind firewalls and add role assignment in logicapps to access those stoarge a/c 's as mentioned in document

Comment: Thanks Vijaya. I will go through the document and update you!

Comment: Is there any limitation on filecontent size? What is the max size allowed?